# How to fix Retrieving the value that comes after the minimum value of the time field of each service

Tags: sql

I would like to retrieve the value that comes after the minimum value of the time field **for each service** example service number 2:
[image]

the hour value: 13:54 this is a value that comes after the minimal value which is 11:09

I tried this query that runs all the array and returns the value after the minimum value but it's not what I want to have :

```
SELECT DetailCircuitFacture.Heure
FROM detailcircuitfacture
where DetailCircuitFacture.Heure NOT IN (SELECT MIN(DetailCircuitFacture.Heure)  from detailcircuitfacture)
```

I tried to integrate the previous query with this one :

```
SELECT Libellé,min_heurs
FROM (
SELECT Service.Libellé AS Libellé, 
MIN(DetailCircuitFacture.Heure) AS min_heurs
FROM detailcircuitfacture
JOIN Service ON Service.CodeSce=detailcircuitfacture.CodeSce
GROUP BY Service.Libellé
HAVING detailcircuitfacture.Heure  NOT IN (SELECT MIN(DetailCircuitFacture.Heure)  from detailcircuitfacture)
)
```

i expected the output :

service1 13:54

service2 ....

etc
but the actual result is no result and no error

thanks for help by advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I don't understand you well, but maybe it could be like this:

```
select s.Libellé,d1.Heurs
from detailcircuitfacture d1
  join (
    select min(DetailCircuitFacture.Heure) minHeure
    from detailcircuitfacture
    ) d2
    on d1.Heure>d2.minHeure
  join Service s
    on s.CodeSce=d1.CodeSce
order by d1.Heurs ASC
```

Comment: thanks for your response you are near of what i want. your query gives me also the rows after minimum +1 i want only minimum + 1 only the hour that is after the minimum of each service ( group by service) minimum +1 group by service.libelle

Comment: Please, add your expected output. The output that you provide is not enough to understand what you want